# Why printing out the characters “” (147, 148 ascii) does not work as expected on c++?

Tags: c++, g++

I do not understand what's going on here. This is compiled with GCC 10.2.0 compiler. Printing out the whole string is different than printing out each character.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   char str[] = "“”";
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
   std::cout << str[0] << str[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
“”
��
```

Why are not the two outputted lines the same? I would expect the same line twice. Printing out alphanumeric characters does output the same line twice.

Comment: Maybe something to do with how your editor encodes that literal ... what does `std::cout << strlen(str) << std::endl;` show for the length of the string? (It shows as 6 on my Windows/Visual Studio system - which is not what I was expecting!)

Comment: That string literal actually ends up being something like `"\xe2\x80\x9c\xe2\x80\x9d"`

Comment: Presumably your file is saved in utf-8, printing individual bytes from the string will not produce valid utf-8 characters

Comment: @Adrian Mole strlen gives me 6 too.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili with sizeof the result is 7

Comment: ASCII goes to 127, and only has `"` and `'`.

Comment: I guess the source code file is encoded with UTF-8, I wonder if it would "fix" the issue if you did change the encoding to a different code page (which actually has `“` as 147).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bear in mind that, on almost all systems, the maximum value a (signed) `char` can hold is `127`. So, more likely than not, your two 'special' characters are actually being encoded as multi-byte combinations.

In such a case, passing the string *pointer* to `std::cout` will keep feeding data from that buffer until a zero (nul-terminator) byte is encountered. Further, it appears that, on your system, the `std::cout` stream can properly interpret multi-byte character sequences, so it shows the expected characters.

However, when you pass the individual `char` elements, as `str[0]` and `str[1]`, there is no possibility of parsing those arguments as components of multi-byte characters: each is interpreted 'as-is', and those values do not correspond to valid, printable characters, so the 'weird' `�` symbol is shown, instead.

Comment: I thought chars could hold 8 bits, and that each value corresponded to the ascii table were these special characters are defined as 147, and 148 source:https://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @ABR Yes, a `char` is (by definition) one byte, and a byte is (almost always) 8 bits. However, the `char` type is generally a *signed* value, so the range is `-128` thru `+127`. Trying to assign `147` will result in wrap-around to a negative value, which will not correspond to a printable character.

Answer (score 3):

`"“”"` contains more bytes than you think. It's usually encoded as utf8. To see that, you can print the size of the array:

```
std::cout << sizeof str << '\n';
```

Prints 7 in my testing. Utf8 is a multi-byte encoding. That means each character is encoded in multiple bytes. Now, you're printing bytes of a utf8 encoded string, which are not printable themselves. That's why you get `�` when you try to print them.